# Where text in one cell matches text another cell populate the value in the adjacent cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a formula that when I paste text into `D2:D11`, the adjacent cell (`E2:E11`) contains a formula that checks cells `J2:J7`. If the text in `D2` matches any data in `J2:J7`, it populates the number contained in the adjacent cell `I2:I7` into the corresponding cell `E2:E11`.

For example where `D1 = Glasgow FC`, it checks `J2:J7` matches with `J4` and populates the figure at `I4` (3) into `E2` when the formula is copied into the other `E` cells it will also populate `I4` (3) into `E5` and `E8`.

Hope this makes sense

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified if the order of the Organisation is tied to the Service ID. Here's a solution where the second organisation has Service ID = 2 etc.

[image]

## The Formula

```
=MATCH(D2;$J$2:$J$7;0)
```

#### Explanation

- Place this formula in the `E2` like in your picture
- `D2` is the first row of `Employers`
- `J2:J7` is the list of organisations

What you may realize is that you will have to adjust this `J2:J7` if you expand on the list. I would **highly** suggest making a new Table with these organisations. Then, we can just reference `TableOrgs[Organisation]` and it will work regardless of how many rows you have.

Another little detail that you might see, is that `Reading Borough Council` will result in a `#N/A` error. This is because it could not be found in the list. You could use `=IFERROR(theFormulaHere; "")` to display nothing if it was not found.

*Best of luck!* ^_^